# CGContextDrawPath hangs in aa_distribute_edges

Tags: cgcontext, cgpath

A user is reporting that my app is freezing and that he has to force quit.   The app does not crash, it just hangs.  He sent me the document and the conditions but I cannot reproduce the hang on my computer.   He sent me the crash log, which is very long, but it appears that the problem occurs during a CGContextDrawPath.  Below is

```
 17 CGContextDrawPath + 199(CoreGraphics + 323893)[0x7fff515da135] 1 - 17
         17 ripc_DrawPath + 318(CoreGraphics + 324473)[0x7fff515da379] 1 - 17
         17 ripc_Render + 381(CoreGraphics + 99778)[0x7fff515a35c2] 1 - 17
         17 RIPRenderCoverage + 1639(CoreGraphics + 101667)[0x7fff515a3d23] 1 - 17
         17 aa_render + 632(CoreGraphics + 559938)[0x7fff51613b42] 1 - 17
         1 aa_distribute_edges + 436(CoreGraphics + 404181)[0x7fff515edad5](running) 1
         2 aa_distribute_edges + 302(CoreGraphics + 404047)[0x7fff515eda4f](running) 2 - 3
         1 aa_distribute_edges + 436(CoreGraphics + 404181)[0x7fff515edad5](running) 4
         5 aa_distribute_edges + 302(CoreGraphics + 404047)[0x7fff515eda4f](running) 5 - 9
         1 aa_distribute_edges + 436(CoreGraphics + 404181)[0x7fff515edad5](running) 10
         3 aa_distribute_edges + 302(CoreGraphics + 404047)[0x7fff515eda4f](running) 11 - 13
         2 aa_distribute_edges + 436(CoreGraphics + 404181)[0x7fff515edad5](running) 14 - 15
         1 aa_distribute_edges + 302(CoreGraphics + 404047)[0x7fff515eda4f](running) 16
         1 aa_distribute_edges + 436(CoreGraphics + 404181)[0x7fff515edad5](running) 17
```

The routine where this occurs is drawing a plot and the path is just lines between points.   The user has told me that the problem goes away for plots with less points.  The plot that hangs the app has 60,000 or more points.    I sent him a version that writes to a log file at different places in this code and it appears that the freeze is happening inside CGContextDrawPath.  Nothing appears in the log after that line of code is reached.    I'm at a loss to debug this without access to his computer.  Anyone have any suggestions.  I have the rest of the crash (hang) log, if that will help.

UPDATE: 12-Aug-2019
While I cannot reproduce this "hang" on my macbook, I did install xcode and ran the project on my wife's macbook and can reproduce the "hang" while in Xcode.   The code leading up to the hang is

```
CGPathRef path = CreatePath();
if(path) {
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CFRelease(path);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, foreColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context,0.75);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    return true;
}
```

The CreatePath() function is a MoveTo, followed by a loop of LineTo.  I used CGPathApply and printed out the entire list of elements and each element is exactly what I expected, i.e., the MoveTo followed by a bunch of LineTo.

The code hangs in CGContextDrawPath, and when I paused the app in Xcode it is always inside "aa_distribute_edges"

Not only can I not figure out what is causing the hang, I also don't know why the same code works without hanging on my laptop.

UPDATE: 13-Aug-2019
Still Stuck.  Running Xcode on both computers I can step into the assembly code and follow the same app drawing the same document step identically all the way into RIPRenderCoverage.  But inside this routine the computer that doesn't hang doesn't go into aa_render, while the computer that hangs goes into aa_render.   Once inside aa_render, the computer that hangs goes into aa_distribute_edges and then seems to get into what seems like an infinite loop.

Gosh, I'm stumped.  Desperate for any suggestions here.

UPDATE: 13-Aug-2019 (pm).  Just discovered that I can avoid the hang if I reduce the line width, i.e., CGContextSetLineWidth(context,0.5), instead of what I used above.   What am I not understanding about Core Graphics?

UPDATE: 19-Aug-2019.  I found that the hang depends on the display used.  Specifically, retina displays hang.  If I add NSHighResolutionCapable to app's info.plist and set it to NO, then the problem goes away and I can use any line width.  So, something in my code is wrong for drawing in high resolution.

UPDATE: 24-Aug-2019. I did let it "hang" for over an hour and it never finished in high res mode.   The same draw with NSHighResolutionCapable off is instant (few milliseconds).      I also get a hang with NSHighResolutionCapable on if I plot a small circles at each point instead of connecting with lines.

UPDATE: 06-Sep-2019.  Turning NSHighResolutionCapable off keeps my app from crashing on Retina displays, but users are complaining that the windows now look a little blurry on retina displays.

Answer (score 0):

I think Core Graphics is suffering from a severe case of overdraw

This answer is an speculative guess based on the evidence you provided in your question.

I believe this hang is a long hang but not a full on deadlock, based on a similar [report I read with poor plotting performance in the R language on macOS](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2017-July/012443.html).

Assuming your issue is similar then if you left it running for a long time, it would eventually render.

In CoreGraphics/Quartz2D I *think* drawing happens on the CPU. That said, I wasn't able to find definitive information from [Apple's current docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_overview/dq_overview.html) as to whether Core Graphics uses the CPU or GPU, but there is some [old information](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2005/04/macosx-10-4/14/) saying that only an old technology called Quartz Extreme allowed GPU rendering in Core Graphics, but was disabled by default. Since the hang is in a function called `ripc_Render` it looks like it is indeed rendering the lines on the CPU.

Since the source code for Core Graphics is not available to inspect, I'll have to speculate, but here is what I think is happening:

1. When you call `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, it append a new point to an array of points. So far, the work is linear `O(n)` with respect to the number of points.
2. Calling `CGContextDrawPath` sends the data to the CoreGraphics CPU renderer, which is essentially rendering a bitmap image. The work required to render the line is a function of more than n (the number of points), it is also a function of the line width, screen density, and line length. This is why reducing line width or running on a non-retina screen improve performance.

### Solution: Reduce Points

The resolution on a 4K monitor is 3840x2160 (WxH). If you're plotting a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) (in the mathematical sense, meaning all X values are unique), then you can only display 3840 of those points on a 4K monitor without overlap.

Once you have more points than will fit on the screen, eliminate some of the path points by reducing calls to `CGContextAddLineToPoint`. You can use one of the following (untested) puedo-code algorithms, where `DP[]` is your array of data point and WxH is the screen resolution in pixels.

- SKIP: if `DP.length > W`, then only draw every `(DP.length/W)` data point
- AVERAGE: if `DP.length > W`, then draw `W` data points, where each `W` is an average of `DP.length/W` data points.
- RANGE BAR: if `DP.length > W`, then draw a vertical line between the minimum and maximum `Y` values  in each set of `DP.length/W` data points.

Using either algorithm puts an upper bound on the number of lines you draw which should significantly reduce the time spent in `CGContextDrawPath`.

Comment: The X values are unique, but the data can be noisy.  I had already implemented a solution by reducing the points, and that does work with NSHighResolutionCapable on.   The app looks at scientific datasets and it is important to give the user the option of plotting all points.   Enabling this option works fine with  NSHighResolutionCapable off.  Seems odd that I have to remove this feature to be compatible with retina display.

Comment: fyi, for noisy data I cannot use AVERAGE, since that will make the noise appear smaller than actual.    And using SKIP could lose a narrow feature.   My solution is to find the max and min in the range of DP.length/W and plot a vertical line at X between the max and min.